# Count the number of occurrences of Null in a column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am relatively new to Tableau and I am wondering if there is a way to calculate null values in a column.
I have a column called Email of type string and want to know how many people have not entered their email i.e. Null.

I tried to create a calculated field with 
count(ISNULL([Email]))

But this gives me the total count and not the count of null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot count `NULL` since `COUNT` ignores `NULL`s.

You can do this, though:

`SUM(IF ISNULL([Email]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

---

Per your additional comment, if you wanted to count where two fields are both `NULL` then:

`SUM(IF ISNULL([Email]) AND ISNULL([Phone]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

You can continue this for any number of fields, as needed.

Comment: What if i want to count rows which have both phone and email as null?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter for that field. Set it to only show you `Null values`, and set the measure to `Count` instead of the default `Sum`.

[image: filter dialog]

Answer (score 0):

> You can create another column where all null values are set to 1 and anything else to 0, >then count that. It should be something like
>
> ### >COUNT(IF "null" THEN 1 ELSE 0)

A working syntax for that would had been:

SUM(IF ([Your field] = null) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END)

Answer (score -2):

You can create another column where all null values are set to 1 and anything else to 0, then count that. It should be something like

```
COUNT(IF "null" THEN 1 ELSE 0)
```

Comment: Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`