# Count NULL and other values in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to make chart displaying count number of values in column (null as one value).

[image]

Comment: Can you add more context to the question?

Comment: Read about Count() and CountD()

Comment: the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047174/shripal-mehta worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Tableau, so I've only been able to solve your problem partly -

1. In `Rows` Shelf, add your `Field_Name`.
2. In `Marks` Card, double click to create a fresh criteria, and enter text - `COUNT([Field_Name])`
3. Choose category of the criteria as `Text` instead of Details

This creates a list of unique items in your List and their counts; **except** for the Null values (My dataset contains 2 `Null` entries). 
Note: The counts of the null values can be checked by clicking the `Null  0` row, and selecting the `Full Data` tab from `View Data...`

Image for Ref -
[image: Count Representation]

[image: View Data - Full Data]

Comment: based on @Nick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684831/11047174), one can't calculate `Null` values using `count` aggregate function,
But you can however write a separate aggregate function like this - `SUM(IF ISNULL([Field_Name]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 1):

Upon digging into Tableau fundamentals, I learnt that you can do this with 2 simple steps:-

1. You may place the attribute in `Row` Shelf.
2. In the Navigation Panel on the left, under `Measures` section, you'll find something called `Number of Records` OR `ExcelWorksheetName (Count)` in italics. Drag that into the Data area of the visualization.

This approach gives you the Null counts as well! :)

Image for Ref -
[image]